# jQuery Smooth Scrolling on Page Load

Tags: jquery

I'm using this jQuery Script to do Smooth Scrolling (Found on CSS-Tricks.com):

```
/** Smooth Scrolling Functionality **/
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function filterPath(string) {
  return string
    .replace(/^\//,'')
    .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
    .replace(/\/$/,'');
  }
  var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
  var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');
  var urlHash = '#' + window.location.href.split("#")[1];

  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(event) {
    var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
    if (  locationPath == thisPath
    && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
      if (target) {
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
          event.preventDefault();
          $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400, function() {
            location.hash = target;
          });
      }
    }
   });  
  });

  // use the first element that is "scrollable"
  function scrollableElement(els) {
    for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
      var el = arguments[i],
          $scrollElement = $(el);
      if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
        return el;
      } else {
        $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
        var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
        $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
        if (isScrollable) {
          return el;
        }
      }
    }
    return [];
  }

});
/** END SMOOTH SCROLLING FUNCTIONALITY **/
```

It works fantastic, except for one thing, I want it to work where if someone goes directly to the url e.g. `http://domain.com/page.html#anchor` it smooth scrolls to that anchor from the top on page load, right now it immediately goes to the page anchor unless they've clicked on an anchor.  I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 26):

If it is not too late for answer then here you go.... 
Here is a modification of PSR's code that actually works for smooth scrolling of page on load:

http://jsfiddle.net/9SDLw/1425/

```
$(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $('#anchor1').attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

Better version:

http://jsfiddle.net/9SDLw/1432/

```
$(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.myclass').offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

All you need to do in this script is to replace the "myclass" with a class or ID of the control located on the page you want to scroll to.

Naveed

Comment: While this is good, it doesn't answer the question directly. The OP wanted to smooth scroll to an id that is specifically used in the url hash: `example.com/#example`

Answer (score 5):

I found this to be the best way to do what I want so far:

```
/** Smooth Scrolling Functionality **/
var jump=function(e)
{
    //alert('here');
   if (e){
       //e.preventDefault();
       var target = jQuery(this).attr("href").replace('/', '');
   }else{
       var target = location.hash;
   }

   jQuery('html,body').animate(
   {
       scrollTop: (jQuery(target).offset().top) - 100
   },500,function()
   {
       //location.hash = target;
   });

}

jQuery('html, body').hide();

jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $(document).on('click', 'a[href*=#]', jump);

    if (location.hash){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
            jump();
        }, 0);
    }else{
        $('html, body').show();
    }
});
/** END SMOOTH SCROLLING FUNCTIONALITY **/
```

Answer (score 2):

@ Talons post ...

> I found this to be the best way to do what I want so far:

Me 2, but I had to make some changes to it.

```
var target = jQuery(this).attr("href").replace('/', '');
```

**1. Why replace the "/"?**

In my case it makes the url...

"http:// [my domain]/ [my page]/ [my anchor]" ...look like...

"http:/ [my domain]/ [my page]/ [my anchor]"

and...

**2. Chrome (my current version: 40.0.2214.115 m) doesn't like the following Line...**

```
   jQuery('html,body').animate(
   {
       scrollTop: (jQuery(target).offset().top) - 100
   },500,function()
   {
       //location.hash = target;
   });
```

*Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http:/ [my domain]/ [my page]/ [my anchor]*

I found out that jQuery cannot work with "offset" when "target" is a full href like http:// .../#anchor.

**to fix 1.**

replaced:

```
var target = jQuery(this).attr("href").replace('/', '');
```

with:

```
var target = jQuery(this).attr("href");
```

**to fix 2.**

replaced:

```
   jQuery('html,body').animate(
   {
       scrollTop: (jQuery(target).offset().top) - 100
   },500,function()
   {
       //location.hash = target;
   });
```

with:

```
if(target.search('/') === -1) { //only do scroll if page with anchor is the currently loaded page
   jQuery('html,body').animate(
   {
       scrollTop: (jQuery(target).offset().top) - 100
   },500"easeInOutExpo"); // requires easing
}
```

Now works perfectly for me, without any errors. 
Please comment on this one, for I am pretty new in js/jquery...

thx @Talon

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using [**.scrollTop()**](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

[**SEE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9SDLw/961/)

Comment: That works similar to the function in my question but it doesn't solve the problem if they navigate directly to the domain anchor (http://domain.com/page.html#anchor  it immediately goes to the anchor if they type that into the url rather than smooth scrolling to it.

Comment: You can use animate for that

Comment: @Talon i updated my code now check it once .It is working as you required now

Comment: No not really sorry, it only activates on the click, it needs to activate on both the page load and the click.

Answer (score 0):

These days you can scroll on page load with only javascript. I like to set a `setTimeout` just to give it some time before scrolling.

```
if (window.location.hash) {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  var element = document.querySelector(hash);
  
  if (element)
    element.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth",
      block: "nearest",
      inline: "start",
    });
}
```

Comment: This is great but currently only a Working Draft. Not ready for production websites as Safari (macOS/iOS) does not yet support the _smooth_ behavior option. See [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). Let's hope Apple takes care of this soon.