# Flask - href to anchor on a different page (navigation bar)

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am using Flask to develop a web app. On the home page (index.html), the navigation bar navigates one to specific sections on the page using anchors:

```
<a class='text' href='#body2'>calculate</a>

<a id="body2"></a>
```

On the home page, there is a form which links you to a new page (output.html). I want the same navigation bar to navigate a user to the previous page (index.html) and the specific sections. I have written the navigation links on the second page as shown below:

```
<a class='text' href="{{ url_for('index') }}#body2">calculate</a>
```

When I click the navigation links, the new page does not load. However, this is the strange thing, when I inspect the navigation link element in my browser and click the link through the inspect client, it does take me to the correct page/section.

If I remove '#body2' from the above line, it successfully navigates me to the previous page, but not to the specific section.

(If you want to physically try out the navigation links on the web app, use the following link:
http://yourgreenhome.appspot.com/ - Enter some random values into the blank form entries and it will take you to the second page. It is running through Google's App Engine but this is definitely not causing the problem because the problem still occurs when I run the site on local host).

Comment: <a class='text' href="{{url_for('.index', _anchor='body2')}}">calculate</a>

I have tried the above line, which I found from another stackoverflow thread, but this does not work either. Same problem: click the link on the site and it doesn't navigate, but when I inspect the element and click the link, it does work.

Comment: If I right click the links and open in a new window, they work. But not when I click them directly. But removing the anchors allows it to work.

Comment: The issue is not related to flask. In `smoothscroll.js`, you are adding scroll affect to every anchor link in your page. So, when home link on the top left corner is clicked, the animation is triggered on the second page. However, since element "#body" doesn't exist in that page, animation code breaks. You can check dev console: `Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`. You probably shouldn't load `smootscroll.js` in second page, and rethink animation on page load for the first one. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534851/jquery-smooth-scrolling-on-page-load) may help.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in `smoothscroll.js`

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      event.preventDefault();

      var hash = this.hash;


      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

In `advpy` page, `$(hash).offset()` is undefined, thus `top` is undefined. Because you are preventing the default event (`event.preventDefault();`) the click on the link doesn't occur.